# How to get old record on vehicle tracking database for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am newbie to SQL Server 2008.

I use a vehicle tracking system. This system use a database which storage vecihle data (GPS, Speed, Adress etc.) I use SQL Server Management Studio to look up database. I can see only tables which belong to current month. There is a table for each day. That is ok. But I can't see the tables which belong to older months. Anyway I can access pass data from vehicle software (ASPX). There is many (.ndf) file in my E drive.

How to get pass vecihle data which is not seen on database but can accessing from software

Comment: . . I would suggest talking to your DBA and requesting permission to look at the older tables.

Comment: .. One table for each day ... and "That is ok"? ... oh my god!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to attach the other mdf files to a SQL Server instance (a different, non-production one I would suggest).

(Right-click on the database node in SSMS and select the Attach... option)

Comment: There is only one mdf files. Ndf files is 38 more. Attach option not working

Comment: sorry read ndf as mdf. Do you have access to the web app source code to see what queries it runs? Are there any stored procedures in your database that the app might be using?

Comment: source code is not mine . I am trying to understand database structure of vecihle tracking system to integrate BI tools. My main target is querying past data(for example : 8 Agust 2013) on partioned tables or databese